# Binary tree pointer error

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, tree

I have three functions to managa a binary tree :

```
static void insertion(Noeud* &top, Noeud *newNoeud)
{
    if(top == NULL)
        top = newNoeud;
    else if(newNoeud->nbr < top->nbr)
        insertion(top->left, newNoeud);
    else
        insertion(top->right, newNoeud);
}

static void affichage(Noeud* &top) //displaying
{
    if(top != NULL)
    {
        affichage(top->left);
        affichage(top->right);
        cout << "\n" << top->nbr;
    }
}

static Noeud* recherche(Noeud* &top, int nbr) //searching 
{
    while(top != NULL)
    {
        if(top->nbr == nbr)
            return(top);
        else if(nbr < top->nbr)
            top = top->left;
        else
            top = top->right;
    }
}
```

however I keep getting an error saying that I am violating the access when trying to read a memory spot. I am guessing this has to do with my pointers but I can't guess what it is.

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger? Where exactly does it crash? Have you tried valgrind, if you're on Linux?

Comment: Since `static Noeud* recherche(Noeud* &top, int nbr)` means what it means in C++, you're passing `top` by reference, `top = top->left;` resp. `top = top->right;` will destroy your tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `recherche` changes the `top` which it shouldn't.

Does this even compiled ?

```
static Noeud* recherche(Noeud* &top, int nbr) //searching 
{
    while(top != NULL)
    {
        if(top->nbr == nbr)
            return(top);
        else if(nbr < top->nbr)
            top = top->left;
        else
            top = top->right;
    }
}
```

This doesn't always return a value...

should be something like that:

```
static Noeud* recherche(Noeud* &top, int nbr) //searching 
{
    Noeud* it = top; //use a temporary pointer for the search.
    while(it != NULL)
    {
        if(it->nbr == nbr)
            return(it);
        else if(nbr < it->nbr)
            it = it->left;
        else
            it = it->right;
    }
    return it; //always return a value.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your search method makes your top node not point to `top` anymore.